# Setup AWS codecommit VCS in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, version-control, aws-codecommit

Previously, I've added VCS to my projects using Github. I wanted a private repository so I switched to AWS CodeCommit. Now I've Created a repository on AWS CodeCommit. How can I configure the git in Android Studio for CodeCommit repository?

Answer (score 1):

Integration of code commit with the Android studio is two step process:
1. configure git to your android studio
2. setup a code commit repository for your project exactly the same way you do for github or any git.

The git setting for android studio are available at : File --> open Setting> Default Settings-->Version Control -->Git

For seeting up code commit you can refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit more on the previous answer, you'll want to use Git Credentials[1] to authenticate with CodeCommit. Basically, these are username/password credentials you generate through the IAM console for your IAM user. You will supply these to Android Studio to use for authentication to AWS.

Also, this documentation page[2] doesn't explicitly show how to set up Android Studio, but it does show how to configure various other IDEs, so it might help you with setup as well.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide.html